# How to reinstall package ubuntu-advantage-tools

Tags: 18.04, package-management, dpkg

I tried to install FEniCS on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS with the following commands (from fenicsproject.org site):

`sudo apt-get install software-properties-common`
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fenics-packages/fenics`
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install fenics`

The operations completed with an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):<br>
  File "\<string>", line 2, in \<module><br>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'uaclient'<br>
dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-advantage-tools (--configure):<br>
installed ubuntu-advantage-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1<br>
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ubuntu-advantage-tools<br>
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

In fact, executing:

`dpkg --list | grep ubuntu-advantage-tools`

I got:

```
iF ubuntu-advantage-tools 27.2.2~18.04.1 amd64 management tools for Ubuntu Advantage
```

It seems that the package is not copmpletely configurred. So I tried to reinstall it:

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-advantage-tools`

but it completed with an error:

```
E: Internal Error, No filename for ubuntu-advantage-tools:amd64
```

Finally I tried to purge the package and install it once more:

`sudo apt-get purge ubuntu-advantage-tools`

but it also didn't work:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):<br>
  File "\<string>", line 2, in \<module><br>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'uaclient'<br>
dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-advantage-tools (--remove):<br>
installed ubuntu-advantage-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1<br>
Errors were encountered while processing:<br>
 ubuntu-advantage-tools<br>
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What is the reason of this behaviour and what should I do to get it working?

Comment: Does the command `python3 -c 'import uaclient'` complete successfully (silently), or do you get `ModuleNotFoundError`? If the latter, then it's likely to be your system Python installation that is broken. Did you try to modify your Python installation?

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Nmath - In fact I did some manipulation with outputs, because I run commands on Linux, but for communication on askubuntu.com I use Windows. Of course I could copy the outputs to Windows, but instead of that I typed the outputs by hand. My fault. Another reason was that in my preview I had no line breaks so I had to insert them by hand. Maybe there is some better solution, but, as you see, it was my first mail, so I didn't find how to do it. As to update and upgrade - I did both commands (the output is long, so I do not include it), but it didn't help.

Comment: Robie Basak - thank you for the hint. In fact, executing this command I got ModuleNotFoundError. But when I run the same with python3.7, everything was ok.  My python3 is linked to python3.8, but I found that the module uaclient is taken from directory echo $PYTHONPATH

Comment: @RobieBasak Please convert your remark into an answer so that other users can build on it. Also a question with an answer attracts more users that have the same problem as the OP. Your contribution may help them.